# Unable to fully print a page containing iframes in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a webpage which has 4 iframes alongwith bunch of other things. When I try printing the whole page in chrome using window.print(), it prints everything except the iframes. Is there a way to make it print whole page including the iframes. I have control over the pages hosted in iframes, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
[Javascript Print iframe contents only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)

```
window.frames["iframeID"].focus();
window.frames["iframeID"].print();
```

Comment: I know how to print individual iframes. What I want to know is how to go about printing a parent document which has multiple iframes.

Comment: How about loading the whole document inside one single iframe and printing that one?

Comment: So you mean extracting html from my 4 iframes and dumping that into 1 iframe? Dont think that will work, as that would mean essentially getting rid of all iframes altogether, which I did try in first place. It messes up the styling if I use div's instead of iframes.

Comment: No, I mean loading the page which includes all the iframes into a single iframe. So make a new html file and add 1 iframe that it's src would be your main page(that includes the 4 iframes). Then try to print that.