# How to Print iframe content

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to print iframe inner content. In this iframe URL page also having one more iframe.

i have used this URL into my iframe.

```
<iframe width="700" height="500" src = "https://www.cashpayment.com/Public/PaymentCenterLocator?MerchantID=946">
```

I want to print this content.

Comment: Have you seen this [Javascript Print iframe contents only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)??

Comment: Yes i seen.none  ifram working . if used inside one more iframe that not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'iFrameTagId', 'height=500,width=500');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>title</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);//iFrame data
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
```

Or you directly open this page and use below code while page load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.print();
    setTimeout('window.close();', 100);
});
```

**Updated Code**

```
function iprint(ptarget) {

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'ptarget', 'height=500,width=500');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>title</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write($(ptarget).html()); //iFrame data
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    } 

<iframe name="theiframe" id="theiframe" width="700" height="500"  src = "http://localhost:54649/WebSite6/Default.aspx"></iframe> 
 <input type="button" class="btninput" value="print iframe" onclick="iprint('#theiframe');" />
```

Comment: i have tried it's not working. I am using MVC 4

Comment: you print with new chtml page?

Comment: No. Just want pass to printer that iframe content only