# Trying to print pdf through iframe, get error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, printing

In Chrome it works fine, but in Firefox I get this error:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'
```

My code:

```
<iframe src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/CV.pdf" id="PDFtoPrint"></iframe>
<a class="" href="#" title="Print CV" onclick="document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint').focus();document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint').contentWindow.print();"></a>
```

I see this bug on [firefox forum](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444).Is it solved?

Any other solutions?

Thanks!

EDIT: on IE I get this error:

```
SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @ThomasWTupper The document from the `iframe` is on the same website. I put it in the same folder. I tried with `http://` and `http://www.` and I get the same error. According to your link, it should work, right?

Comment: It is almost certainly a security exception.  But have you tried the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only

Comment: @ThomasWTupper Ok, that one is working. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful - I didn't examine it thoroughly, but it looked to me that this is fragile and not working across all browsers.  Test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like:

```
<script>
    function for_print(){
      window.frames["printf"].focus();
      window.frames["printf"].print();
      var newWin = window.frames['printf'];
    }
</script>

<iframe style="display:none;" id="printf" name="printf" src="demo.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="demo.html" id="PDFtoPrint" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```