# Printing iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to print an iframe with the code below:

```js
function printFunction() {
    window.frames["printf"].focus();
    window.frames["printf"].print();
}
```

```html
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>
```

But the window does not open, and when I use another code:

```js
function printFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

```html
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe >
```

The window opens, but prints the whole page (parent page), and not just the iframe.

Button "print" calls function `printFunction()` with onclick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9616706/1305911

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Print iframe contents only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)