# Iframe cross origin issue while printing the Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, powerbi

I have an iframe in my webpage. I have set its source as Power BI Report Url. I want to print the iframe content. I have taken sample code from [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)
I am facing cross `Blocked a frame with origin "http:/xxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

How to resolve this cross-origin frame issue?