# Print data in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, printing, angular2-template

I want to print some data that I have in a variable. The code I have is:

```
    public printData(data) {
      let printContents, popupWin;
      printContents = data;
      popupWin = window.open('', '_blank','resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
      popupWin.document.write(`
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Print</title>
          </head>
          <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
          </html>`
      );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

It works fine but i get something like this:

[image]

and i don't want the want the window behind the printer options. I want to show the user only:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this using an `iframe` have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only -- The accepted answer might be what you are looking for

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: NP.. Happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a IFrame, remember not to use window.open in this case...