# Trigger PDF Download PHP - Laravel 7

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf, laravel-7

I have a simple report page, and I am using `Laravel 7` to build it.

[image]

I want to trigger auto-download a PDF with that view.

What would be the most lightweights I should look into?
I did a quick Google, and I saw so many options.

I decided to try [this](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-pdf-tutorial-generate-pdf-with-dompdf-in-laravel/) and did all the steps, below is my final code

## Final Codes

Note this line : `$pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.be.baby.report', get_defined_vars());`

```
public function downloadReportPDF($id) {


    $code = Request::get('code'); 
    $baby = Baby::where('adminCode',$code)->where('id',strtolower($id))
    ->orWhere('readOnlyCode',$code)->where('id',strtolower($id))
    ->first();
    
    if($baby){


        $inputs    = Request::all();
        $interval  = 'week';

        if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
            $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
        }

        switch ($interval) {
            case 'day':
            $q = BabyLog::where('created_at', '>', now()->today());
            break;
            case 'week':
            $q = BabyLog::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek());
            break;
            case 'month':
            $q = BabyLog::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth());
            break;
            case 'year':
            $q = BabyLog::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear());
            break;
            default:
            $q = BabyLog::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            break;
        }


        $logs = $q->where('babyId',$baby->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->groupBy(function ($log) {
            return $log->created_at->format('m/d/y');
        });


        // dd($logs);

        $graphData = [];

        foreach($logs as $date => $logsOnThatDay){


            $pee      = 0;
            $poop     = 0;
            $feed     = 0;
            $medicine = 0;
            $sleep    = 0;


            foreach($logsOnThatDay as $logOnThatDay){

                // if(strtotime($logOnThatDay->created_at) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))){

                if($logOnThatDay->type == 'pee'){
                    $pee++;
                }

                if($logOnThatDay->type == 'poop'){
                    $poop++;
                }

                if($logOnThatDay->type == 'feed'){
                    $feed++;
                }

                if($logOnThatDay->type == 'medicine'){
                    $medicine++;
                }

                if($logOnThatDay->type == 'sleep'){
                    $sleep++;
                }


                $graphData[$date]['pee']      = $pee;
                $graphData[$date]['poop']     = $poop;
                $graphData[$date]['feed']     = $feed;
                $graphData[$date]['medicine'] = $medicine;
                $graphData[$date]['sleep']    = $sleep;

            }
        }


        array_pop($graphData);

        //PDF 
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.be.baby.report', get_defined_vars());

        return $pdf->download('file.pdf');
    }


}
```

It is working, when I visit the route :

> Route::get('/baby/{id}/report/download','BabyController@downloadReportPDF');

But the styles seems very messed up.

- Images are missing, and so on.

[image]

How do I improve on that ?

---

## Updated

I've updated my images links to remote url now... they loaded now.

[image]

Somehow styles still messed up.

I even tried inline style for my padding, and still rendering wrong... :(

## report.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Bunlong Heng">
    <meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Report</title>

    <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="{{$baby->babyProfilePath}}?q={{microtime()}}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{$baby->babyProfilePath}}?q={{microtime()}}" type="image/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{$baby->babyProfilePath}}?q={{microtime()}}" sizes="152x152">


    <link  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color: white; 
            color: black;

        }

        h5 {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #86868b;
        }

    
        .text-poop {
            border: #ffb54c 1px solid !important;  
            color: #ffb54c; 
        }

        .text-pee { 
            border: #46b8da 1px solid !important;  
            color: #46b8da;
        }

        .text-medicine { 
            border: #ffdf0a 1px solid !important;  
            color: #ffdf0a;
        }

        .text-sleep { 
            border: #ca88ff 1px solid !important;  
            color:  #ca88ff;
        }

        .text-feed { 
            border: black 1px solid !important;  
            color:  black;

        }



    </style>


</head>


<body>

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-sm-2 "></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">


                <h1>{{ $baby->babyName }}</h1>

                <hr>

                <h5> Interval : {{ $interval }}ly. </h5>
                <h5> Today : {{ date('D F j, Y, g:i a') }}</h5>
                <h5> Parents : {{ $baby->name }} ({{ $baby->email }})</h5>
                <h5> URL : {{ env('APP_URL') }}/baby/{{ $baby->id }}/report?code={{ $baby->readOnlyCode }}</h5>

                <hr>

                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

                <hr>

                <table class="table skill-table">
                    <thead class="thin-border-bottom">
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>Ago</th>
                        <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Xhg4Iwi.png" /> </th>
                        <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/peU9Bas.png" /> </th>
                        <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y3rrj9T.png" /> </th>
                        <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/zQrE1o5.png" /> </th>
                        <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/yCk62aM.png" /> </th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>


                        @foreach ($graphData as $date => $graph)

                        <tr>

                            <td >
                                {{$date}}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ DateHelper::ago($date) }} ago.</td>

                            <td >
                                <a style="padding: 5px; " class="text-poop">{{$graph['poop'] ?? '' }}</a>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <a style="padding: 5px; " class="text-pee">{{$graph['pee'] ?? '' }}</a>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <a style="padding: 5px; " class="text-feed">{{$graph['feed'] ?? '' }}</a>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <a style="padding: 5px; " class="text-medicine">{{$graph['medicine'] ?? '' }}</a>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <a style="padding: 5px; " class="text-sleep">{{$graph['sleep'] ?? '' }}</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        @endforeach

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">


                function hexToRgb(hex, opacity=1) {

                    var h=hex.replace('#', '');
                    h =  h.match(new RegExp('(.{'+h.length/3+'})', 'g'));

                    for(var i=0; i<h.length; i++)
                        h[i] = parseInt(h[i].length==1? h[i]+h[i]:h[i], 16);

                    if (typeof opacity != 'undefined')  h.push(opacity);

                    return 'rgba('+h.join(',')+')';

                }



                var url_string    = window.location.href;
                var url           = new URL(url_string);




                var data  = {};
                if(url.searchParams.get("interval") != null){
                    data.interval = url.searchParams.get("interval");
                }

                // console.log(data.interval);  

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/baby/{{$id}}/graphsData',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: false,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                    },
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response){
                        // console.log(response);


                        keys = [];
                        
                        peeData      = [];
                        poopData     = [];
                        feedData     = [];
                        medicineData = [];
                        sleepData    = [];

                        $.each(response, function(key,val) {

                            keys.push(key);

                            peeData.push(val.pee);
                            poopData.push(val.poop);
                            feedData.push(val.feed);
                            medicineData.push(val.medicine);
                            sleepData.push(val.sleep);


                        });



                        // console.log(peeData, poopData, feedData, medicineData, sleepData);


                        var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
                        Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
                            draw: function() {
                                originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

                                var chart = this.chart;
                                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                                var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
                                if (index) {
                                    var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
                                    var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

                                    ctx.save();
                                    ctx.beginPath();
                                    ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top);
                                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
                                    ctx.textAlign = '#ff0000';
                                    ctx.fillText('NOW',0,0);
                                    ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);
                                    ctx.stroke();
                                    ctx.restore();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        var options = {  weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: false };
                        var fullDayText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-us', options);


                        var chartColors = [hexToRgb('#fff',1), hexToRgb("ccc",1)];

                        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                        canvas.height = 2000;


                        var renderChart = function() {

                            new Chart(canvas, {
                                type:'bar', 
                                data:{
                                    labels: keys,
                                    datasets:[
                                    {
                                        label: 'poop',
                                        data: poopData,
                                        backgroundColor: hexToRgb('#ffb54c',.5),
                                        borderWidth:1,
                                        borderColor: hexToRgb('#ffb54c',1),
                                        hoverBorderWidth:3,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'pee',
                                        data: peeData,
                                        backgroundColor: hexToRgb('#46b8da',.5),
                                        borderWidth:1,
                                        borderColor: hexToRgb('#46b8da',1),
                                        hoverBorderWidth:3,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'feed',
                                        data: feedData,
                                        backgroundColor: hexToRgb('#fff',.5),
                                        borderWidth:1,
                                        borderColor: hexToRgb('#ccc',1),
                                        hoverBorderWidth:3,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'medecine',
                                        data: medicineData,
                                        backgroundColor: hexToRgb('#ffdf0a',.5),
                                        borderWidth:1,
                                        borderColor: hexToRgb('#ffdf0a',1),
                                        hoverBorderWidth:3,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'sleep',
                                        data: sleepData,
                                        backgroundColor: hexToRgb('#ca88ff',.5),
                                        borderWidth:1,
                                        borderColor: hexToRgb('#ca88ff',1),
                                        hoverBorderWidth:3,
                                    }
                                    ],
                                    lineAtIndex: new Date().getHours()
                                },
                                options:{
                                    legend:{
                                        display:true,
                                        position:'right',
                                        labels:{
                                            fontColor:'#000'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                            });

                        };

                        renderChart();
                        setTimeout(renderChart(), 1000);



                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });


            </script>




        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You can use JavaScript to print that

Comment: Oh cool, will it auto download for users

Comment: You can use https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF it's comparatively easy to use I believe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript see here

Comment: Please don't close this, I want to it Laravel friendly, I will update my post show more... that I tried.

Comment: FYI, I haven't flagged your question. Why don't you build the pdf in a html page using js and css sending the data from laravel backend? Is that something you might consider?

Comment: @cyber8200 I think u should re-check css, js in link, script tag. I think the problem in path of these files. try Internal css to determine the problem

Comment: @LengKeng : Can you help me please ? I updated my posted with my entire blade.view

Comment: @LengKeng : Please see that I tried move the padding style into inline and still not taking any effect.

Comment: @cyber8200 From my experience, if you want to generate pdf from server then try. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy
This will let you run the js before creating the pd file. with charts, chartjs will not work when creating pdf server on the server side. Try highchart or google chart instead

Comment: pass data into view instead of using ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use trigger print you can do it by using `window.print`, it's will show print dialog that contain print as pdf. example code

```html
<input type="button" value="Print" onClick="window.print()">
this will show in print preview
```

For print another page you can use iframe. you can hide it using CSS too. example:

```
<button onclick='window.frames["printf"].print();'>print</button>
<iframe id="printf" name="printf" src="test.html" height="1%" width="100%" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

I tried print page contain chartjs and works 100%, you can [test it out](https://yaskur.com/iframeprint.html)

If you want to trigger download as PDF, you  should use package. JS solution is [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)  and PHP/laravel solution is [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) . Both packages will not print exactly as browser render especially if you are using CSS3 or Image source from local. You need to custom the CSS and asset that compatible for both packages.

If you are using laravel dompdf you need to change below code:

```
<img src="/media/image.png" />
```

to

```
<img src="{{ public_path('/media/image.png') }}">
```

you can using `asset()` but you need activate remote asset in laravel dompdf too.

You can check DomPDF CSS Compatibility [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility).

Comment: I just change my images to use remote url, they loaded now, but somehow styles still messed up and chart is not displaying....

Comment: @cyber8200 check style/CSS compatibility here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility , for the chart how did you make it? if  made by JS or HTML5, I dont think dompdf support it.

Comment: I like this suggestion that you shared `onClick="window.print()">` how can I do that if the page that I want to print is not on that page..

Comment: Do you mean print from another URL page? Maybe you can use iframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only/9616706

Comment: @cyber8200 check my example using  hidden iframe https://yaskur.com/iframeprint.html , it works using html5 or javascript too. that url contain chartjs and works 100%

Comment: Can u share a working example ? Ur link show empty white page

Comment: it has small print button on the top left corner