# Printing a browser page that is not open (Javascript and/or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I'm wanting to be able to theoretically pass a URL to a window.print() (yes I know you cannot pass a url to this function) via a button. Then the print window would pop up with a page/article that you are not currently on in the browser.

For example: Let's say I am on Facebook.com and I have a share button for an article that pops up on Facebook.com. Lets say that when you click share, there is a print button that when clicked it will print the article (let's say this article is google.com for example). When I am on Facebook.com I want to be able to print Google.com using that share button WITHOUT having to even go to the website/page Google.com.

Is this something that is possible with javasript/Jquery. I have been doing a lot of research into it but not finding anything that would fit this criteria.

Thank you for your help!

I have tried setting up a jquery function that takes in a doc url and print the window but it continues to print the current page that I am on.

I have tried doing a lot of research on the idea but am continuing to see problems where people are only trying to print the page that they are currently on.

Comment: You can not really control it because of being in a different domain.

Comment: If you can get the content on the page, then you can use `@media print` / `@media screen` to show/hide elements so that print looks completely different from what you see on the screen.   Here's a cut-down simple version :  https://jsfiddle.net/4vts9x8p/   run the fiddle then ctrl-P to get a print-preview.    The problem is getting the remote content.

Comment: @epascarello if it exists in the same domain, would you be able to control it?

Comment: you can window.open and print it. You can use an iframe and print it. But once it is in another domain same origin policy and x frame options limit it.

Answer (score -1):

It is always possible if you work on it, with a little bit of creativity.
I imagine you can fetch the content of the page through iFrame element, keep the element hidden and then print the content of it.
[Found that Link that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)

Comment: Most servers don't like iframes, eg they'll give:  `Refused to display '...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`   Or `Refused to frame '...' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'`