# Send PDF files directly to client printer

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to print a generated PDF from through javascript using:

```
document.labelGenerator.printAll();
```

but unfortunately, this code only works in Internet Explorer and not in Chrome.

Can someone please help me?

I know that this question have already been asked but unfortunately it had never been answered: [How to send a pdf file directly to the printer using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074070/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-directly-to-the-printer-using-javascript)

Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: Javascript isn't supposed to be able to print directly.

Comment: On IE it works. but if you have a suggestion of how I can print silently, please let me know. I am using asp.net c#

Comment: My suggestion is don't. Users don't like it. That's why browsers don't normally allow it.

Comment: That is my requirement basically. that is why i am trying to implement such a functionality