# How to print all pdf's from a folder without showing the print dialog using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the pdf from a specific folder without showing the print dialog.
As of now i had written it is showing the printer dialog.

Is it possible to print the file to the default printer without asking the dialog

Comment: No it's not possible. It may lead to attacks also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a pdf without visually opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639769/print-a-pdf-without-visually-opening-it)