# How to trigger print if I am using dompdf stream and displaying using blob

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, printing, dompdf

How to trigger print if I am using dompdf stream and displaying using blob.

I am using laravel dompdf and vuejs.

I am able to display pdf in modal.

Now I Need to open print dialogue using my print button not from pdf.(Its client requirement)

I tried some solution like :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444702 (saying "document is not ready to print", obviously print() triggers before pdf loading.)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239785 (Goes to infine loop always get `undefined`)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010113 (Only works in chrome, in firefox `Error: Permission denied to access property "print"`)

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: So you want to trigger printing the PDF by using a button in an HTML page? What is your modal setup? Using frames/iframes or a PDF embedded in the HTML?

Comment: Currently I am using <object> tag, but I am ready to use anything to get this done

Comment: It's a big kludgey, but you could have the button trigger a re-render of the PDF. The second render would include some PDF JavaScript to initiate a print. Try rendering [this document](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.2/www/test/script_javascript.html). Ensure dompdf is [configured to include PDF JS](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.7.0/src/Options.php#L176) in the render (the default). Of course, whether or not it works depends on the viewer application.