# Print PDF directly from url

Tags: javascript

I want to print directly a pdf from a url.

I tried window.open(url) but it suggest me to save it. (Because of the .pdf)
I just want to print the url directly

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to open the file first, by open I mean that you either open it in a new tab, or use a iframe. With a iframe you could style it so it wouldn't be visible. This way you could hide that the file has been opened and then you could invoke print in the iframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a pdf file directly to the printer using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074070/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-directly-to-the-printer-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the file in the same tab of the browser you can use:

```
window.open(url, "_self");
```

Or also you can try:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

If by printing you mean in a printer you can use http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the file first in new tab and from there you can download or you can show in same page and from there also you can download

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="pdfdiv">
                 <a class="media" href="./yourPdfFIleLocation.pdf">Click Me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
```