# Printing PDF from browser using Aspose.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, aspose

I want to force a PDF to print from browser by clicking a link. It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205180/how-to-print-a-pdf-from-the-browser) that embedding javascript using a PDF toolkit can make this possible, so would anyone know if/how this can be done with Aspose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, brilliantly simple and works a treat! (You can also use a stream instead of a path name in OpenPdfFile)

```
//create PdfViewer object
PdfViewer viewer = new PdfViewer();
//open input PDF file
viewer.OpenPdfFile(@"c:\input.pdf");
//print PDF document
viewer.PrintDocument();
//close PDF file
viewer.ClosePdfFile();
```